# $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(2^n-2^i)$ can be divided by $n!$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

My student asked me the following question:

> Prove that for any natural number $n \geq 2$, the product $$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(2^n-2^i)$$ is divisible by $n!$.

I would like to ask for a nice solution to this question. My idea was using induction and Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: You might have something really interesting to add to https://oeis.org/A002884

Comment: I'm trying a combinatorial proof. No luck so far.

Comment: and to[P(n)/n! = A053601] (http://oeis.org/A053601)

Comment: See here too : https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h421474p2381071

This is a problem from Turkey's Math Olympiad, 1996.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A nice solution is given by the natural embedding of $S_n$ into $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_2)$.

Here $S_n$ is the symmetric group of $n$ elements. Every element of $S_n$ permutes the canonical basis of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$, hence gives an $\mathbb{F}_2$-linear automorphism of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$. This embeds $S_n$ as a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_2)$.

Now it only remains to say that the cardinalities of the two groups are $n!$ and $\prod_{i = 0}^{n - 1}(2^n - 2^i)$, respectively.

---

By replacing $\mathbb{F}_2$ with $\mathbb{F}_q$ for any prime power $q$, one proves in the same way that $n!$ divides $\prod_{i = 0}^{n - 1}(q^n - q^i)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solution is really nice. Though I do not know if we can translate it to an elementary way so that a student in grade 10th can understand.

Comment: Ah... I didn't know it was a 10th grade student. Obviously this solution (and I believe the question itself) involves higher level maths. In 10th grade one might be able to understand some basics of group theory, e.g. by examples such as $S_n$ or $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^\times$, but this question also involves vector spaces over finite fields in a non-trivial way. That really isn't easy to explain...

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** For each odd prime $p$, if $p^k |m \leq n$ then
$$p^k |2^{\frac{p-1}{p}m}-1$$ and hence 
$$p^k| 2^{n}-2^{n-\frac{p-1}{p}m}$$

Comment: Instead of $n$ in your first line it would be $n!$ is it not?

Comment: @Piquito No, it is $n$. The idea is too look at ALL possible occurences of $p$ in  $n!$, one at a time.

Comment: Then, what happen when $p^k$ does not divide $m$?. Regards.

Comment: By the way, noting $P_n$ the product above one has $P_{n+1}=2^n(2^{n+1}-1)P_n$ so if $2^n(2^{n+1}-1)$ were always divisible by $n+1$ the proof by induction would be immediate. But it is not the case, many times it is but many times it is not. Hence many times $P_n$ is divisible by $m!$ for $m\gt n$. In the simple case of $P_4$ it is divisible by $7!$ ($m$ almost the double of $n$)

Comment: @Piquito Consider all numbers $1 < m_1 < m_2< ...<  m_k \leq n$ which are divisible by $p$, meaning $m_1=p, m_2=2p,..$. Ignore everything else... For each $j$ you can write $m_j=p^{l_j} \cdot q$ where $p \nmid q$. Now, the power of $p$ in $n!$ is exactly $l_1+l_2..+l_k$.... The hint shows that for each $j$ we have $p^{l_j}| p^k| 2^{n}-2^{n-\frac{p-1}{p}m_j}$. Note that these terms are different for different $j$'s. Deduce from here that the power of $p$ in the numerator is LARGER than the power of $p$ in the denominator. Since this holds for each $p$, you can conclude that....

Comment: @Piquito As for the second comment, that's exactly why I am suggesting this prppoach... Note that if $n+1$ does not divide $2^n(2^{n+1}-1)$ there must be an odd prime dividing $n+1$ which does not divide $(2^{n+1}-1)$. The solution above is using the fact that this will divide $2^{n-\frac{p-1}{p}n}$ with the right power.

Comment: Thanks very much N. S. (I have no chat).

Comment: Thanks very much! Just one more question: Is there any way to prove it without knowing the idea of Euler's theorem beforehand?

Comment: @Dynamic Not sure, I would expect a combinatorics proof to be possible, but cannot see it yet.

Comment: @Dynamic If you want to use modular arithmetic, it is easy to see via the pigeon hole principle that $p^k|m \leq n$ implies that there exists some $i_m$ such that $p^k |2^{n}-2^{i_m}$. But you also need to show thatwe can pick $i_m$ such that $m \neq k$ implies $i_m \neq i_k$, which I don't see how to prove.