# Prove that $n !$ is a divisor of $ \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(2^{n}-2^{k}\right) $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, contest-math

> Prove that for any natural number $n, n !$ is a divisor of
> $
> \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(2^{n}-2^{k}\right)
> $

i have already seen it here [$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(2^n-2^i)$ can be divided by $n!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3387000/prod-i-0n-12n-2i-can-be-divided-by-n) but my doubt is different.

**Solution** -

for $p=2$ we can easily prove that $v_{2}\left(\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(2^{n}-2^{k}\right)\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} v_{2}\left(2^{n}-2^{k}\right) \geq n-1$ > $n-S_{2}(n)=e_{2}(n)$

let now $p>2$ ,and author proves that

$
v_{p}\left(\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(2^{n}-2^{k}\right)\right) \geq\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p-1}\right\rfloor
$  ( using FLT)

and

$
e_{p}(n)=\frac{n-s_{p}(n)}{p-1} \leq \frac{n-1}{p-1}<\frac{n}{p-1}
$
and since $e_{p}(n)$ is an integer, we must have
$
e_{p}(n) \leq\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p-1}\right\rfloor
$

***now i did not get this last step***.
why $
e_{p}(n) \leq\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p-1}\right\rfloor
$
we know that $x>[x]$ so how we get reversed signs ???

thankyou

Comment: One traditional approach is that the product counts the number of ordered bases of an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb F_2.$ And we can divide this set of bases into equivalence classes of size $n!$.

Comment: That argument also works if you replace $2$ with any prime power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an ineteger $n<5.5$ .Then it implies $n\le \lfloor5.5\rfloor=5$

This is the same thing.Since $e_p(n) < \frac{n}{p-1}$ and $e_p(n)$ is an integer .We have that, $e_p(n) \le \lfloor \frac{n}{p-1}\rfloor$

Comment: Ohh ,yes silly me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You know that $e_{p}(n)$ is **an** integer smaller than $\frac{n}{p-1}$.

At the same time $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p-1}\right\rfloor$ is the **largest** integer smaller than $\frac{n}{p-1}$.